# How does Simplify deal with contradictions in the assumptions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

**Context**
Sometimes `Simplify` does generate a warning when the assumptions are self-contradictory.
Take this example:

```
v={x,x+1}; 
Simplify[v, x==0 && x+1==0]
```

Some other times it doesn't generate any warning and outputs a solution. Take this example:

```
v={x,x+1}; 
Simplify[v, x==0 && Conjugate[x+1]==0 && x\[Element]Reals]
```

This last example outputs `{0,1}` without any warning.

**Question**
Hence, before using `Simplify`, should one take upon themselves to first verify the self-consistency of the assumptions? This is not a problem, I just want to be sure to understand the proper workflow when resorting to `Simplify`.